# Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.nutch.crawl.Generator (Nutch 1.14)

Tags: apache, nutch

I am using Nutch 1.14 on Mac. I have set JAVA_HOME and I have been able to run Nutch successfully before, but I had to re-download Nutch and now I am having the error above.

I think it must have something to do with Apache Ant, which I never ran inside the Nutch folder - I can't figure that step out. Any help?

Comment: Could you provide the detailed commands to install/build and run Nutch? Sounds like the class path isn't configured properly.

Comment: @SebastianNagel I downloaded apache-nutch-1.14-src.tar.gz from the Apache website, unzipped it and put that folder in my work directory along with some other folders including the apache ant folder. From there, I went into the conf folder and changed site.xml, urlfilter.txt, etc to fit my needs. I have not done anything else to Nutch, though I am running Java JDK 1.8. I never ran any builds, but I don't remember doing that when I got Nutch to work the first time I used it. I don't know what build commands to run or how.

Comment: Of course, when starting from the source package Nutch needs to be compiled, see https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial

Comment: @SebastianNagel Of course, I read this page, but since I am new to Mac, I don't understand how to "Run ant in this folder" (one of the steps in option 2)